# ¿Cómo se obtiene el nombre de autor, título del libro, y año de publicación del primer libro de cada autor?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Estoy practicando SQL. En una tabla sencilla llamada Libros tengo el `ID, Titulo, Autor, Publicadora, AnioPublicacion`. ¿Cómo puedo obtener el primer libro publicado de cada autor?

Por ejemplo, si tengo los siguientes datos en la tabla:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| ID | Titulo                                                         | Autor                | Publicadora                                                    | AnioPublicacion |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | La polifonía clásica                                           | Samuel Rubio         | Biblioteca "la ciudad de Dios", Real Monasterio de El Escorial | 1956            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 2  | Historia de la música espańola 2. Desde el Ars Nova hasta 1600 | Samuel Rubio         | Alianza Música                                                 | 1983            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 3  | Officium Hebdomadae Sanctae de Tomás Luis de Victoria          | Samuel Rubio         | Instituo de música religiosa de Cuenca                         | 1977            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 4  | The notation of polyphonic music                               | Willi Apel           | The Mediaeval Academy of America                               | 1953            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 5  | Tomás Luis de Victoria: A guide to research                    | Eugene Casjen Cramer | Garland Publishing Inc.                                        | 1998            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 6  | Studies in the Music of Tomás Luis de Victoria                 | Eugene Casjen Cramer | Ashgate                                                        | 2001            |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], primer pregunta que gestor de bases de datos usas? por que colocaste mas de uno, segundo podrías añadir que has intentado?

Comment: segundo, que regla de tu ejercicio determina cual es el primer libro publicado de cada autor? con base en eso sabremos como ayudar

Comment: Basado en el año. El editor sería DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: En base de datos, el gestor de base de datos es el motor. En tu caso, el motor es sqlite. DB Browser es solo el programa que usas para conectarte. Lo que preguntas es simple, intentaste algo? obtuviste el año menor para cada autor?

Comment: @xxelecmanxx proveyó la respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basado en el año de publicacion como especificas mas arriba,necesitarias agrupar los datos por autor, y luego con MIN(anioPublicacion) obtienes el registro con el menor anio de publicacion del autor (primera publicacion de un autor), la consulta sql que necesitarias, seria similar a:

```
 select  autor,titulo,min(anioPublicacion)
 from libro  
 group by autor
```

Espero te sirva, hice pruebas con los datos que publicaste en un gestor  sqlite, Saludos.

Comment: excelente. Muchas gracias.